# SwiftUI: performance problems with ScrollView + LazyVStack + ForEach

Tags: ios, swiftui, memory, swiftui-scrollview

### Problem Outline: What I set out to build

I'm trying to build some sort of reader app and I'm running into severe performance issues with several approaches. If you know how to do this, please read the next paragraph and then jump to the "Help, please!" section at the end.

I want to render the items of an array of type `[Item]` (saved locally) as a scrollable view in SwiftUI, using `Text` (or rather some custom `ItemView`, but `Text` runs into the same problem) to display the individual items, sorted by `item.id`. The array has around 50,000 items, and about 10 items are onscreen at any given time. For brevity, let's assume the following `Item` definition and auto-incrementing id's starting at 0:

```
struct Item {
  var id: Int
  var text: String
}
```

### Approaches

#### Approach 1: Initially load small array and fetch dynamically

My first idea was to preload around 100 items (centred around a `targetId` that I want to display initially) in an `itemArr` and pass this `itemArr` to a `ForEach`, like so:

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
  ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
      ForEach(itemArr, id: \.id) { item in
        Text(item.text)
      }
    }
  }
  .onAppear { proxy.scrollTo(targetId, .center) }
}
```

Once the user scrolls to within 20 items of either end of `itemArr`, I would fetch 100 further items, let's call them `newItems`, by calling `fetchItems(from id: Int, to: Int) -> [Item]`. I would then prepend/append those items to `itemArr`.

This worked fine for appending, but prepending crashes the app. This makes sense, as I understand now, because prepending `newItems` to `itemArr` makes `ForEach`'s diffing go crazy, as every item changes its position in the array and the scrolling position get's messed up too. (Appending, on the other hand, leaves the items from the original `itemArr` in place, which means that `ForEach`'s diffing recognises that the currently displayed items are unchanged, and `LazyVStack` prevents the appended items from being loaded.)

#### Approach 2: Preload the entire array without the text, and update the array dynamically

Given that I can't prepend, my next thought was to preload the entire array (with `n+1` items) into memory, but without the text (for the obvious memory-saving reason), like so:

```
var itemArr: [Item] = (0...n).map { i in Item(id: i, text: nil) }
```

Note that this requires a change in the `Item` definition to:

```
struct Item {
  var id: Int
  var text: String?
}
```

I would then populate around 100 items in `itemArr` with text and try to render as follows:

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
  ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
      ForEach(itemArr, id: \.id) { item in
        if let text = item.text {
          Text(text)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  .onAppear { proxy.scrollTo(targetId, .center) }
}
```

But this performs fairly badly: long initial load and large memory consumption. (And gets worse: for `n=500,000`, the app doesn't load on an iPhone 11 and consumes 1.5 GB of RAM on the simulator)

#### Thought 3: Somehow make the array use negative indices

The whole problem is quite ridiculous, really, because all that would be needed is for an array to either allow for negative indices *or* to tell `ForEach`'s diffing at which indices it should start comparing the new and old arrays, thus avoiding the problem that prepending `newArr` changes the relative position of the items in `itemArr`.

**Is there some `RandomAccessCollection` that can be passed to `ForEach` that allows for this approach?**

#### Approach 3: Custom `RandomAccessCollection`

I followed up on the above thought and implemented `struct NegativeArray` conforming to `RandomAccessCollection`, in the hope that `ForEach`'s diffing algorithm uses the indices of the `RandomAccessCollection`, but it doesn't.

```
struct NegativeArray<Element>: Sequence {
    var array: [Element]
    var firstIndex: Int
    
    func makeIterator() -> NegativeArrayIterator<Element> {
        return NegativeArrayIterator(self)
    }
}

struct NegativeArrayIterator<Element>: IteratorProtocol {
    let negativeArray: NegativeArray<Element>
    var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    init(_ negativeArray: NegativeArray<Element>) {
        self.negativeArray = negativeArray
    }
    
    mutating func next() -> Element? {
        guard currentIndex < negativeArray.array.count else {
            return nil
        }
        let element = negativeArray.array[currentIndex]
        currentIndex += 1
        return element
    }
}

extension NegativeArray: Collection {
    var startIndex: Int {
        return firstIndex
    }
    
    var endIndex: Int {
        return array.count + firstIndex
    }
    
    func index(after i: Int) -> Int {
        return i + 1
    }
    
    subscript(position: Int) -> Element {
        return array[position - firstIndex]
    }
}

extension NegativeArray: BidirectionalCollection {
    func index(before i: Int) -> Int {
        return i - 1
    }
}

extension NegativeArray: RandomAccessCollection {
  // Conforms, because the index (Int) conforms to Strideable
}
```

### Help, please!

I'm sorry for the long post, but I wanted to at least outline my thinking and what I've tried so far. I'm new to SwiftUI and hopefully there is an easy solution to this. The avenues that I currently see as promising:

- A `RandomAccessCollection` that mimics negative array indices. (Nope, see edit "Approach 3" above)
- Understanding why the app consumes 1.5 GB of memory on simulator, given that we load an array of 500,000 items using 32 bytes each (as is the case in the above `Item` struct), which amounts to an array size of 1.5 MB, or three orders of magnitude less. What else is thus happening?

Can you help me in any way? Thanks!

### Code example

When I run this on simulator, it consumes 1 GB of memory before rendering the first `Text` view. Deleting the `scrollTo(_:anchor:)` has no effect.

```
struct Item {
    var id: Int
    var text: String?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var itemArr: [Item] = (0...500_000)
        .map { i in Item(id: i, text: nil) }
        .map { item in
            if (310_000...310_500).contains(item.id) {
                return Item(id: item.id, text: "Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum")
            } else {
                return item
            }
        }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
          ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
              ForEach(itemArr, id: \.id) { item in
                if let text = item.text {
                  Text(text)
                }
              }
            }
          }
          .onAppear { proxy.scrollTo(310_150, anchor: .center) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `LazyVStack` loads lazily, but it does not "recycle" views like `List`. With LazyVStack initially if your screen holds 10 items, you'll only load 10 items, but scroll to the 1000th item and you'll have 1000 items in memory.

Comment: I know, but this isn't the problem here.

Comment: Can you add `ItemView`? Maybe that is causing all the item views to be loaded in the LazyVStack. I'm positive that is the case, because in my case, the running instance consumes 30 mb and the view is pretty smooth

Comment: Try adding Codable, Hashable and Equatable to Item. Also since you are dealing with a lot of data consider CoreData as a cache so you get faulting.

Comment: @Aswath It's also not the `ItemView`, the problem persists when swapping `ItemView` for a simple `Text`. (I've now added sample code at the end too.)

Comment: @loremipsum I've added `Codable`, `Hashable` and `Equatable` to no avail. I haven't looked into Core Data much yet (I'm new to Swift), but given that the code sample that I just added at the end of my question doesn't work, it's too early to worry about this...

Comment: @Aswath Does my code sample at the end of the Q also only consume 30 MB in your case? That would indeed be strange.

Comment: SwiftUI is not the best tool for 500,000 items a UIKit approach would be much more efficient. Putting 500,000 items in memory even without UI would be very heavy.

Comment: Well, sadly it appears to be so. But isn't this a bit silly, given that it's easy to dynamically append the array in `ForEach` (i.e. scrolling down), but impossible to prepend the array (i.e. scrolling up)? I still hope that there's some `RandomAccessCollection` solution. // Re 500k items in memory: they would each only consume 32 bytes if initialised with an `id` and `text = nil` and I would update them dynamically.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html

Comment: @Principled ok, this is all guesswork. i think by using `if let text = item.text` SwiftUI creates something along the lines of a `TupleView` that has zero intrinsic height and so the `LazyVStack` loads all the 500000 items into the view. Instead of `if let text = item.text { Text(text) }` this: `Text(item.text ?? "123")` would solve your performance issue since you'd not end up with a Text item with zero height and so you'll have only views that fit inside the screen be loaded

Comment: @Aswath Guesswork, but nice guesswork I believe. Cheers. This indeed solves the performance issue, but only when not using `scrollTo`, since `scrollTo` unfortunately always causes all views up to the scrolled-to id to be initialised (unless they are optional and nil), though not displayed. Thus, when scrolling to id 310,150 (as in my sample code), views 0 to 310,150 are initialised and apparently held in memory, which still consumes around 500 MB (and again, I don't quite get why each view takes up so much memory). -- Do you have an opinion regarding the `RandomAccessCollection` idea?

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for the link. While this will certainly come in handy once I've solved the current issue, I don't see how this helps me here. In my posted sample code, there are only 500 `Item`s with non-nil `text`. The issue rather is that even `Item`s with `text = nil` are initialised (when following @Aswath and using `Text(text ?? "123")`) and then consume 500 MB of memory.

Comment: @Principled I searched a bit and perhaps https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731271 could be what you need?

Comment: @Aswath Thanks! Unfortunately I need to support iOS 16, so the updates to `ScrollView` aren't yet available to me. -- In case you're curious, what I'll try next  is the following: I'll use two `ForEach`s inside the `VStack`, one for scrolling up and one for scrolling down. This allows me to initially populate the `VStack` with few items, and I can always refresh the view onDisappear or when the app enters background, so that long reading sessions won't cram memory.

Comment: I am also a fan of `ScrollView { LazyVStack` approach, but in this case seems `liSt` is better suited. Have you tried using `List` instead (since it has recycling, of the cells)? Also to solve your initial problem with crash on prepending: try to modify array _atomically_, that is: once you get new items, construct the full array on the side, and then replace the old contents with the new _at once_ (so the view needs to rerender once)

Comment: @timbretimbre Cheers for the ideas! I tried modifying the array atomically, but it doesn't solve the issue. I think what happens is that if the reader was at index `n` of `itemArr`, it scrolls back to index `n` of the atomically modified `itemArr`, which is effectively a jump by the number of items I fetched. (As opposed to appending, where the indices of the displayed views don't change and so the ScrollView stays at its last position). -- I haven't tried `List`, since I thought it'd be too restrictive for some features I want to add to the ScrollView, but I'll give it another look tomorrow.

Comment: `List` is the only view available in SwiftUI that recycles views, and will most likely solve your first set of problems (though you may get issues with it attempting to animate any changes to the items list). I would step back and question the usability of any sort of scrolling content with 50,000 rows, of which 10 are on screen - how is the user supposed to meaningfully scroll around that amount of content?

Comment: @jrturton Well, the point is that it's a reader and that the user should be able to navigate to any position (not by scrolling, but by selecting an appropriate entry point) and then scroll from there. It's conceivable to me that a user might then rapidly scroll down eg. 1,000 rows. -- That's why I initially tried to just load some items around the user's entry point and then dynamically add items around the user's current position. The issue I ran into was an unstable scrolling position when prepending items.